# Display game version

Tags: android, version, game-development, game-maker-studio-2

I want to display version in game. I found `GM_version` method for getting game version. As you see, android version is **0.0.18**. However, version is shown as **1.0.0**. Can you explain me, what am I doing wrong?

GMS2 version: 2.3.x

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The method you are using is right ( `GM_Version` ), but there is actually a problem with GMS 2.3 when using that function on android, I had the same issue and after asking on the forum it seems like they reported it and will be fixed on next patches, best of luck!

Comment: Thank you @yousfi-mohamed-walid for your answer. Then for now, I should write version manually.

Comment: I am afraid that's your only option. If you are doing it manually then define it as a macro, it's more suitable

Comment: After your answer, I checked yoyo games forum. There is a bug about that. https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/gm_version-not-working-on-2-3.78276/

Comment: I think, this bug is not hard to solve, but we have that in 2.3.x